# distribute items equally inside a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to distribute items equally inside a recyclerview

My layout for the items inside the recyclerview is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_parent_layout_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"> 

           <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_V_icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/myschoools" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_V_action_text"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="My Schools"
            android:textColor="@color/drawer_background"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My recyclerview layout is

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_itemset_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/recycleView_background"
            tools:itemCount="3">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I'm loading the recyclerview with a horizontal orientation using the below

```
RecyclerView recyclerView3 = findViewById(R.id.drawer_itemset_3);
ArrayList<ItemData> itemData3 = praperData(3);
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter3 = new RecyclerViewAdapter(itemData3,getApplicationContext(),2);
recyclerView3.setAdapter(adapter3);
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
recyclerView3.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

I'm getting the following result, I tried to change the linearlayout weight to 1 but that have no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the desired effect by changing the recyclerview layout as follows,  However if someone have a better solution please feel free to share it

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/recycleView_background">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_itemset_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/recycleView_background"
        tools:itemCount="3">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```